# Replace backslash in String with Python 3.8

Tags: python, string, cut

I have looked up several methods to extract backslashes from a string in Python, but none of them workes for me. My String looks like the following:

```
s = "This is just a \ test \ string"
```

And i tried the following (because of several answers on stackoverflow):

```
s.replace('\\', "")
```

But this does not work. I get the following output:

```
print(s)
>>> "This is just a \ test \ string"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the backslashes?

Comment: You have to assign the result of the replacement to a variable like so:
new_s = s.replace('\\', "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because string.replace does not alter the string in-place. The following should work:

```
>>> s = "This is just a \ test \ string"
>>> s = s.replace('\\', "")
>>> s
'This is just a  test  string'
```